# Low quality posts review, auto downvote

Tags: feature-request, answers, downvotes, vote-to-delete

I recently saw an answer that was pretty much a link only answer and I did what should be done.
Downvote and left a flag for 'not an answer'.

Then I see another user post the (which I believe is) autogenerated post saying: *'while this link may... Blablabla..'*
And still the answer is only at `-1` score.
I look at the review stats and it was completed with recommend deletion.

Suggestion;
When you recommend deletion of an answer also auto downvote the answer.
I understand that this cost one precious rep point, but if you recommend deletion you can not find it useful, or can you?
Also my gut feeling is that you will get that point back since the answer will get deleted by vote or user deletion.

This will also help clean up SO from this kind of one line, link only answers.

Comment: The current sentiment seems to be less [auto-downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310974/lets-remove-the-auto-downvote-on-validated-vlq-flags-on-questions). Your feature request is not very welcoming ...

Comment: *Also my gut feeling is that you will get that point back since the answer will get deleted by vote or user deletion.* Yes, your gut is right. The down vote reputation cost will be reverted if the post gets deleted.

Comment: @rene I have not read it all on that monster link yet. But that is true that it's not welcoming. It's a good point to keeping it the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really important to downvote posts that are just going to get deleted shortly anyway.  It's not harmful, but it's not particularly helpful either.

Downvote's main value is for posts that *aren't* going to be quickly deleted, and thus will be able to send a useful signal to people reading it (which just won't be happening for a post that gets deleted).

So while there's nothing wrong with you casting a downvote, there's no need to force everyone reviewing the post to cast a downvote as well.